# make css menu 100% wide

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this css code for a responsive menu:

i want to make the menu 100% width of the page, i have tried adding width:100%; on the rmm class but its still not 100% wide, i cannot see whats stopping it.

how can i make the menu 100% width of the page width

```
.rmm {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background:#F36F25;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.rmm a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
    display:block;
    width:auto !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
    display:none !important;
    height:0px !important;
    width:0px !important;
}
/* */


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    display:inline;
    padding:padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}

/* MINIMAL STYLE */

.rmm.minimal a {
    color:#ffffff;
}
.rmm.minimal a:hover {
    background:#666666;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    min-height:36px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:9px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#33333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:9px;
    top:7px;
}

.rmm.minimal .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
    height:2px;
    background:#333333;
    width:25px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
    border-top:1px solid #dedede;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<div class="rmm" data-menu-style='minimal'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#about-me'>About me</a></li>
                <li><a href='#gallery'>Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href='#links'>Links</a></li>
                <li><a href='#sitemap'>Sitemap</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
```

i just tried:

```
.rmm {
    width:100%;
    background:#F36F25;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but still exactly the same, the whole menu just floats left now

Comment: A make a fiddle and post the link.

Comment: for some reason, its not working on a fiddle right but it works fine locally and on my web server

Comment: without a link just some guesses and you have too much irrelevant styles in the code which is confusing so help us to help you!

Comment: I pasted the code into a Fiddle for you. The width seems to be fine at 100%? http://jsfiddle.net/47vhN/

Comment: Are you using Chrome @charlie? If so, check to see if you have some extension causing some issues. Some extensions place HTML on every page.

Answer (score 0):

If your menu has the property `position: relative`, it'll be positioned relative to its first ancestor. Use `position: absolute` for what you want.

For more information, check out [the MDN page on position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

You could also try a [global reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to deal with all `margin` and `padding` issues in one go.

Comment: I don't see a latest edit, but I added a suggestion to the answer. Try out the global reset in the link and see if it works. You'll probably have to restyle some other things, but it will make most browsers function the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the html and body margins.

Add this to your css:

```
html, body
{
 margin:0;
}
```

Comment: still nothing, have added width:100% to this too and still the same

Comment: Hmm, works for me on this codepen:
http://codepen.io/igeorgetaylor/pen/wJBLt     
@charlie, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post screenshot of your menu?
From what we have here, you didn't reset padding on **.rmm ul**, that could be the reason..(?)